# Adding Rails model attribute results in RecordNotSaved errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am extrapolating from a User model given in the Rails tutorial found [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top) to learn more about creating models. I am trying to give a user a confirmation flag, which is initially set false until the user confirms their identity through clicking a link in an automated email sent after registration.

Everything worked before I added the confirmed attribute. I have added a confirmed column to the database through a migration, so it seems to me the error happens somewhere in the `before_save :confirmed_false` logic.

Can someone help me? The user model is below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :password,  :presence     => true,
                        :confirmation => true,
                        :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save :confirmed_false

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  private

    def confirmed_false
      self.confirmed = false if new_record?
    end

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end
                                                              1,1           Top
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your migration, if you set the confirmed column to be a boolean and the default value to be false then you don't need the `before_save :confirmed_false` callback at all as it will always be false when it's a new record.

**Updated**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # unlike before_save it's only run once (on creation)
  before_create :set_registration_date

  def set_registration_date
    registration_date = Time.now # or Date.today
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I was aware that you could set a default in the migration, so I'll definitely try that. But what if I have another attribute like registration_date that needs to be set when the record is created (an attribute that is never set through a constructor), but would be impossible to set as a default in the migration. Would the logic I'm using work for that?

Comment: You could have a `before_create` callback. I'll update my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really figure out what you're trying to do here. It seems like you want to set the default to be confirmed = false, then change it to confirmed = true if the user clicks on the appropriate link and sends you the correct token, or something like that.

So the flow would be something like this:

1. A user record is created with confirmed = false
2. There is no need for a before_filter do do anything yet
3. A user does some action that permits his confirmed column to be set to true
4. Still no need for a before_filter

What's the before_filter for? Are you trying to use it to set a default?